# CollectionView Prepare for Segue in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm having an issue with parsing data over to a detailed viewcontroller with a uicollectionview with custom cell, I have the same data working with a uitableview though.

Here is the prepare for segue section of my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

        if segue.identifier == "movetodetail" {
        if let indexPath = topTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let selectedRow = indexPath.row
            let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailedFirstMainViewController
            detailVC.topImage = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_image2_loc
            detailVC.topTitletxt = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_title
            detailVC.topProfileIMG = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_image_loc
            detailVC.topDes = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_desc
            detailVC.offerStart = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_start
            detailVC.offerEnd = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_end
        }

          else  if segue.identifier == "movetodetail1" {

            guard let cell = sender as? TopCollectionViewCell else {
                    return
                }
                guard let indexPath1 = topCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
                    return
                }

                    let detailVC1 = segue.destination as! DetailedFirstMainViewController
                detailVC1.topImage = QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_image2_loc

                detailVC1.topTitletxt = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_title
                detailVC1.topProfileIMG = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_image_loc
                detailVC1.topDes = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_desc
                detailVC1.offerStart = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_start
                detailVC1.offerEnd = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_end


            }
```

Nothing is being sent across and the detailed view is retuning nil for all properties. I did question if it was an issue with Optionals but I've come to no conclusion or can find any issue with them but I've hit a brick wall.

Any help or example of what is needed would be really appreciated.

Here is the full code for this view:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import SDWebImage
import CenteredCollectionView


struct Qpons {
    let offer_id: Int
    let offer_title: String
    let offer_image_loc: String
    let offer_image2_loc: String
    let offer_start: String
    let offer_end: String
    let company_id: Int
    let address_id: Int
    let user_id: Int
    let offer_type: String
    let offer_desc: String
    let address_line1: String
    let address_line2: String
    let address_town: String
    let address_county: String
    let address_postcode: String
    let address_type: String
    let address_long: Double
    let address_lat: Double
    let address_payments_cash: Int
    let address_payments_cheque: Int
    let address_payments_contactless: Int
    let address_payments_visa: Int
    let address_payments_mastercard: Int
    let address_payments_maestro: Int
    let address_payments_americanexpress: Int
    let address_payments_jcb: Int
    let address_payments_dinersclub: Int
    let company_legal_name: String
    let company_trading_name: String
    let company_type: String
    let company_vat: String
    let company_reg_no: String
    let company_logo_loc: String
    let company_website: String
    let company_facebook: String
    let company_twitter: String
    let company_instagram: String
    var cat_name: String
    let sub_cat_name: String

}

class FirstMainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var topCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topTableView: UITableView!
    var QponsArray: [Qpons] = []



    final let url = URL(string: "http://***/test-site/app_calls/getalloffers.php")



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            downloadJson()


        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()

        dateformatter.dateFormat = "EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy"

        let now = dateformatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
        dateLbl.text = now



        topTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TopTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "topCell")

        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "TopCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil)

        topCollectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "topCCell")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func downloadJson() {
        guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("something is wrong")
                return
            }
            print("downloaded")
            do
            {

                let jsonArray = try JSON(data: data)

                for (index, dict) in jsonArray {
                    let thisObject = Qpons(


                        offer_id: dict["offer_id"].intValue,
                        offer_title: dict["offer_title"].stringValue,
                        offer_image_loc: dict["offer_image_loc"].stringValue,
                        offer_image2_loc: dict["offer_image2_loc"].stringValue,
                        offer_start: dict["offer_start"].stringValue,
                        offer_end: dict["offer_end"].stringValue,
                        company_id: dict["company_id"].intValue,
                        address_id: dict["address_id"].intValue,
                        user_id: dict["user_id"].intValue,
                        offer_type: dict["offer_type"].stringValue,
                        offer_desc: dict["offer_desc"].stringValue,
                        address_line1: dict["address_line1"].stringValue,
                        address_line2: dict["address_line2"].stringValue,
                        address_town: dict["address_town"].stringValue,
                        address_county: dict["address_country"].stringValue,
                        address_postcode: dict["address_postcode"].stringValue,
                        address_type: dict["address_type"].stringValue,
                        address_long: dict["address_long"].doubleValue,
                        address_lat: dict["address_lat"].doubleValue,
                        address_payments_cash: dict["address_payments_cash"].intValue,
                        address_payments_cheque: dict["address_payments_cheque"].intValue,
                        address_payments_contactless: dict["address_payments_contactless"].intValue,
                        address_payments_visa: dict["address_payments_visa"].intValue,
                        address_payments_mastercard: dict["address_payments_mastercard"].intValue,
                        address_payments_maestro: dict["address_payments_maestro"].intValue,
                        address_payments_americanexpress: dict["address_payments_americanexpress"].intValue,
                        address_payments_jcb: dict["address_payments_jcb"].intValue,
                        address_payments_dinersclub: dict["address_payments_dinersclub"].intValue,
                        company_legal_name: dict["company_legal_name"].stringValue,
                        company_trading_name: dict["company_trading_name"].stringValue,
                        company_type: dict["company_type"].stringValue,
                        company_vat: dict["company_vat"].stringValue,
                        company_reg_no: dict["company_reg_no"].stringValue,
                        company_logo_loc: dict["company_logo_loc"].stringValue,
                        company_website: dict["company_website"].stringValue,
                        company_facebook: dict["company_facebook"].stringValue,
                        company_twitter: dict["company_twitter"].stringValue,
                        company_instagram: dict["company_instgram"].stringValue,
                        cat_name: dict["cat_name"].stringValue,
                        sub_cat_name: dict["sub_cat_name"].stringValue





                    )
                    self.QponsArray.append(thisObject)
                }

//                let offers = json["offer_title"].string
//                 print(offers)


                print(self.QponsArray)



                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.topTableView.reloadData()
                    self.topCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print("something wrong after downloaded")
            }
            }.resume()
    }








    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->
        UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "topCCell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell

            let qponImage = QponsArray[indexPath.row].offer_image_loc




            cell.qponImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://****/test-site/images/qpon_logos/\(qponImage)"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))



            return (cell)

    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.QponsArray.count
    }




    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.QponsArray.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topCell", for: indexPath) as! TopTableViewCell



        let qponImage = QponsArray[indexPath.row].offer_image_loc

        cell.qponImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://****/test-site/images/qpon_logos/\(qponImage)"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

        cell.qponTitle.text = QponsArray[indexPath.row].offer_title
        cell.qponDes.text = QponsArray[indexPath.row].offer_desc

        cell.selectionStyle = .none


        return (cell)
    }



    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "movetodetail", sender: indexPath)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "movetodetail1", sender: indexPath)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

        if segue.identifier == "movetodetail" {
        if let indexPath = topTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let selectedRow = indexPath.row
            let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailedFirstMainViewController
            detailVC.topImage = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_image2_loc
            detailVC.topTitletxt = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_title
            detailVC.topProfileIMG = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_image_loc
            detailVC.topDes = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_desc
            detailVC.offerStart = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_start
            detailVC.offerEnd = self.QponsArray[selectedRow].offer_end
        }

          else  if segue.identifier == "movetodetail1" {

            guard let cell = sender as? TopCollectionViewCell else {
                    return
                }
                guard let indexPath1 = topCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
                    return
                }

                    let detailVC1 = segue.destination as! DetailedFirstMainViewController
                detailVC1.topImage = QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_image2_loc

                detailVC1.topTitletxt = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_title
                detailVC1.topProfileIMG = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_image_loc
                detailVC1.topDes = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_desc
                detailVC1.offerStart = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_start
                detailVC1.offerEnd = self.QponsArray[indexPath1.row].offer_end


            }

        }


    }


}
```

The detailed view is as follows for adding the data:

```
class DetailedFirstMainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var topCover: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var topProfile: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textDes: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var offerstartLB: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var offerendLB: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var line2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var line1: UIView!

    var topImage: String = ""
    var topTitletxt: String = ""
    var topProfileIMG: String = ""
    var topDes: String = ""
    var offerStart: String = ""
    var offerEnd: String = ""
```

Comment: You should pass over an object containing the data you want to display. And in the DetailedFirstMainViewController's viewWillAppear delegate method, you should take that data and assign it to the respective UIViews. This approach is much better and should resolve your issues. EDIT: The reason being that the UIViews of the UIViewController aren't laid out or something along those lines.. I'm not entirely sure, but I know that trying to access/edit the views prior to the segue doesn't work.

Comment: `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "movetodetail1", sender: indexPath)` combined with `guard let cell = sender as? TopCollectionViewCell else { return }` seems to fail since `sender` is a `IndexPath` object, not a `TopCollectionViewCell` one.